# How can I find the index value of a parent UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a **UITableView** full of **UICollectionView's**. The UICollectionViews need to know which UITableViewCell they are contained in. I can't figure out how to find this value.

I'm assigning tags to each UITableViewCell by doing this:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell: TableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

    cell.tag = indexPath.row

    return cell
}
```

I need to retrieve that tag again here:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    let tableIndex = //WHAT DO I PUT HERE?

    return masterArray[tableIndex].count

}
```

Comment: Yes, I guess that would work too! Can you help me out?

Comment: You know which `UITableView` a `UICollectionView` belongs to from your data model.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by that... I'm learning. Would you mind elaborating?

Comment: What is the contents of MasterArray at the minute?

Comment: MasterArray contains five arrays of dummy Integers for the time being.

Comment: Ok, So I haven't tested this but, What if you used an Array of tuples as your collectionView array. So an element in the collectionView array would be a (Int, Array()) where you could store the tableViews tag as the int and the collectionView array, (Currently the masterArray) as the array. Then you could set the int in the tableView and retrieve it later.

Comment: That's a great suggestion, but I can't seem to get it working for me. There's got to be a simpler way.

Comment: Why cant you get it to work? It seems like the simplest way. Unless you create an NSObject class with 2 variables (Array and Int) then set the collectionView array to the object and reference it that way? Tuple seem easier to me.

Answer (score 1):

Your `masterArray` is supposed to contain the section arrays in the proper order, then you can simply write

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

  let sectionArray = masterArray[section]
  return sectionArray.count
}
```

Comment: I think you may have missed the question. Its not the count of the sections he's after

Comment: Devster is correct; I need the index of the TableViewCell.

Comment: To count the array that corresponds to the appropriate TableViewCell and tell the contained CollectionView how many items it should return.

Comment: But it's much much easier to put the arrays representing the sections in a master array and use the `section` parameter as index like in my answer

Comment: Well well, it is the count your after then!  Vadian solution is correct as your section arrays should be in proper order.

Comment: The way I have my CollectionView set up is so that it scrolls horizontally, while my TableView scrolls vertically. I understand that creating a CollectionView and displaying my arrays in sections is easier, but it does not achieve the layout that I need.

Answer (score 1):

```
    let tableIndex:Int = 0
    if let cell = collectionView.superview as? UITableViewCell {
        if let tableView = cell.superview as? UITableView {
            if let index = tableView.indexPathForCell(cell)?.row {
                tableIndex = index
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: For some reason, this makes all of my CollectionViews return 0.

Comment: @bkSwifty i know this is 6 years later, but it might be because the row is always 0 and just the section is changing or your `collectionView.superview` is not the `tableViewCell` yet, and you should call again `superview` on `superview`